# The relevance of "El Consejo De Los Dioses" by José Rizal

Tags: spanish-language, jose-rizal, el-consejo-de-los-dioses

José Rizal's play "[El Consejo de los Dioses](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/14796/14796-h/14796-h.htm)" (The Council of the Gods) uncovered some relative aspects covering the social components of the western humanistic viewpoint, (that human beings have the right, capacity, and responsibility to give meaning and shape to their own lives) into a literary context, and in view of the Philippine culture.

A growing outlook that of which striving for self-knowledge is the key for recognition, as Rizal further investigates the genuine importance of the humanly need for information and allegorically represented the rules for a Filipino theoretical thought.

Portraying Olympian gods talking about western artistic norms, it turns into a reference text of scholarly analysis in the Philippines. Justice weighs the scale in giving or finding value in literary texts as they serve more than just an addition to the normative culture of literature itself (formalism) but to create or denote moralism, values, ethics, and the importance of justice as tied with human rights (as previously mentioned).

What are the impacts or relevance of the play in our current or modern age, in your own analysis?

Comment: Rizal was a Filipino author. When you ask, "What are the impacts or relevance of the play in our current or modern age (...)?", are you asking about the current age in the Philippines or about the relevance to any part of the world? The latter might make the question very broad.

Comment: I see it could be about the Philippines or relative to your own country as ith any part of the world.